# What type of mechanism is this?

Tags: design, joint, identification

[image]

Held and rotated by the knurled ends, one in each hand, the silver spokes rise and fall in order for the assembly to rotate. What is it, some companies' salesmen show tool? Found in an old building, unit has no markings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally off topic and not really robotics related but that's an old gearless angle drive.
Kind of like this...

http://www.cal-vantools.com/p-5-90-degree-gearless-angle-drive38.aspx

Comment: While I agree that this question is not very appropriate here, you _could_ make it still a valuable question! That is by providing an answer that is more than a link, which explains how it works and perhaps more importantly, where it is used (preferably with an example of usage in robotics).